Func.Animation plots a blank plot
We have gathered data from lasers measuring the displacement of a target that moves.
One laser for the lateral movement and one for the vertical movement.
From this data I want to animate the target's movement in 2D, (lateral movement/data for the x-axis and vertical movement for the y-axis)
I have looked at several examples like: Making Animations in Python using Matplotlib
The data are basically just two columns with measurements, going like:
Lateral [150.12, 150.16 ......
Vertical [200.03, 200.33 ....]
# %% Import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.animation as animation  # For animating the plots

# Create figure for animation
fig, axis = plt.subplots()

# Create the initial plot with placeholders
animated_plot, = axis.plot([], [], marker='o', color='red', linestyle='None', markersize=3, linewidth=1.2)

# Set plot limits based on the filtered data
axis.set_xlim(min(filtered_lateral_data), max(filtered_lateral_data))
axis.set_ylim(min(filtered_vertical_data), max(filtered_vertical_data))

# Update function for animation
def update_data(i):
# Ensure the arrays are passed as 1D arrays, not nested lists
    animated_plot.set_data(filtered_lateral_data[:i], filtered_vertical_data[:i])

# Optionally update the limits dynamically (if needed)
    axis.set_xlim(np.min(filtered_lateral_data), np.max(filtered_lateral_data))
    axis.set_ylim(np.min(filtered_vertical_data), np.max(filtered_vertical_data))
    
    return animated_plot,

# Create the animation and assign it to a persistent variable
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig=fig,
    func=update_data,
    frames=len(filtered_lateral_data),  # Number of frames should match the length of filtered data
    interval=100,  # 100ms between frames
    blit=False)  # Update the entire plot each frame)

# Keep a reference to anim to prevent garbage collection
plt.gcf().anim = anim

# Show the animation
plt.show()

From this I expect an Animation plot starting from the first position and updating for each position until the end position.
